# Ring Theorem Proof Example

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I prove this is true?

If (S, +, •) is a ring, then for any 'a' which is an element of S

0•x=x•0=0

Where 0 is the + identity on S

Help appreciated.

Comment: Write $0=0+0$, and use the distributive property.

Comment: @BenWest would you mind giving me an example of how to represent it. I am still learning how to correctly represent the proofs.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a \in S$.

$$0 + 0 = 0$$ since $0$ is the additive identity in the ring $S$.

Then, $$a*0 = a(0+0) = a*0 + a*0$$
This is by the distributive law for rings.
Subtracting $a*0$ from both sides (rather, adding the additive inverse of $a*0$ to both sides...) Can you take it from here?